# Implementar um vetor que aceite qualquer coisa

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, array

Eu tenho que implementar um vetor que seja capaz de armazenar objetos qualquer tipo. Por exemplo: `V[3]= valor_int,valor_double,valor_float,valor_String`. Para fazer isso estava pensando em criar um método que fizesse parse dos valores que eu quero inserir, seria a melhor saída para esse caso?

Comment: `vetor v = new Object[3];` ou se puder usar Collections: `ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Precisa detalhar mais o problema para sabermos.

Comment: @DiegoF Obrigado pela dica, não tinha pensado desse modo, eu ia criar um método parse que ia fazer a conversão dos dados mas isso ia fugir do tema proposto, Obrigado vou tentar aqui.

Comment: @bigown O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho que criar um vetor que aceite qualquer dado que eu coloque pode ser uma String,int e um float ou String, Int, String, por exemplo. O jeito que inicialmente pensei para solucionar o problema era fazer um método que convertesse as variáveis, e a minha duvida era se tinha um jeito melhor para fazer ou poderia fazer por parse.Não sei se expliquei melhor?

Comment: Não, você repetiu o que já estava na pergunta. Se pode converter, converta e não se preocupe com ter que aceitar qualquer tipo. Se não pode converter, esse jeito não funciona e precisa de outro, mas precisa entender melhor o problema.

Comment: @bigown Desculpa, vou colocar a ordem do exercício, de repente fique mais claro.
Ordem do Exercício : Criar um vetor, que seja capaz de armazenar objetos de qualquer tipo.

Minha solução era de usar parse, mas percebi que isso não ia atender as necessidades do exercício.

Comment: Este é todo o enunciado do exercício? O que está na pergunta é apenas suposição sua?

Comment: Sim a ordem do exercício é só essa: Criar um vetor, que seja capaz de armazenar objetos de qualquer tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é mais simples do que está na pergunta, só pelos comentários dá para perceber que é só um *array* de objetos. Então basta declarar que o tipo é `Objeto`:

```
Object[] array = new Object[5];
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WEd2lY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fiybtvij-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Object.java).

Mas note que os dados serão armazenados de forma encaixotada. Não será usado um `int`, e sim um `Integer`, embora o valor seja o mesmo, a forma é bem diferente e tem consequências importantes. No momento o Java é assim mesmo e não dá para fazer de forma mais otimizada.

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar implementar a tua resposta também, eu tentei votar na sua resposta como positivo mas mesmo assim ela fica com Zero. Vendo a sua resposta e do outro colega vejo que tenho que aprender muito ainda.

Comment: valeu deu certo aqui, obrigado pela atenção!